Does duplicated data from denormalization affect the performance of vector searches?
In Cassandra, data are usually denormalized to match the query pattern. However, with vector columns, it means duplication of the same vectors. I know vector similarity search and index is very expensive. So will the large amount of duplication affect performance? Is there any better way to model data with vector columns?

I'm sorry but I don't quite understand your question. What do you mean by "duplication of same vectors"? What is duplicated? It would be great if you could provide examples plus any additional background info so we can help you. Cheers!

@ErickRamirez Thanks for taking a look! By duplicate I mean, when data is denormalized, it usually mean duplicate, right? For example, I have lots of articles and each of the article can be in multiple folders. So if I create a Cassandra table that's optimized for query articles in a folder, the columns would be something like "folderID, articleID, articleContent, articleVector". Since an article can be in multiple folders, it means there are duplicated "articleID, articleContent, articleVector" for each folder. Will the duplicated "articleVector" make the performance bad for search?

Vector searches operate on vector embeddings stored in columns with the CQL vector data type. But more importantly, a vector search queries the index of vector data on a single table. Vector searches do not span across multiple indexes nor tables.
Data duplicated across denormalised tables has no bearing on the performance of vector searches in Cassandra since it only queries the index of vectors on a single table.
As a side note, unless you have specific requirements to store vector embeddings of the same columns in different tables then you should avoid duplicating the vector columns. Again, it doesn't matter if there are duplicate copies of a vector column in multiple tables. Its only impact will be increased storage utilisation. Cheers!

The duplicate vectors are in the same table if denormalized . For example, for this schema:
folderID, articleID, articleContent, articleVector
The article can belongs to multiple folders so there will be duplicate articleVector in the same table.
